# Save a string entry to a plist from UITextField in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I would like to know how do I take the value entered into a UItextField and save it into a Plist file strIng entry where the key is " customText ".

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Here's my current view controller:

```
//
//  DetailViewController.swift
//  ConversationalCards
//
//  Created by Avi Tannenbaum on 3/20/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Avi Tannenbaum. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTextField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func ifTextChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

        if case customTextField.text {
            card?.customText = customTextField.text
        }
    }

    var card: Card?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let card = card {
            navigationItem.title = card.name?.capitalizedString
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: card.name!.lowercaseString)
            titleLabel.text = card.title?.capitalizedString

            //Mode label
            modeLabel.text = card.mode?.capitalizedString

            self.setStyle()

            // get custom text from text field
            // Color the text backgrounds and then resize them later for the cards
            //Red
            switch card.color ?? "none" {   // default to none
            case "0":    
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.33, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #EE535D
            case "1":            
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.74, blue:0.70, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #4ABCB2
            case "2":    
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.65, blue:0.09, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #EAA516
            case "3":    
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.40, blue:0.57, alpha:0.3)
                titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #276592
            case "4":    
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.65, green:0.80, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #A6CC63
            case "5":    
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.30, blue:0.35, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #C84D59
            case "6":    
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.40, green:0.34, blue:0.54, alpha:1.0)
            // color hex code #67578A
            default:     
                titleLabel.hidden = false
            }

        // Label style
        // self.titleLabelStyle()
        }
    }



    // font style

    func setStyle() {
    // Script in charge of main label text font and text size
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrajanPro3-Regular", size: 26.0)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(26)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(26)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(26)
    }


/* not working yet this is the function responseble for converting hex values to UIColor values - Avi Tannenbaum
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hexString: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
            let hexColor = hexString.substringFromIndex(start)

            if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
                let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
                if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0X00FF0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

} */


// Style functions
/*
func titleLabelStyle() {
    let title = self.titleLabel
    title.numberOfLines = 0
    title.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: title.intrinsicContentSize().height)
}


 */

}
```

here's my plist file

```
<pre><code><blockquote>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Begin</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string> </string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string> </string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>none</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Getting Started</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>THE COMPLIMENT
        I WANT TO GIVE YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>TALK ABOUT YOUR NEXT VACATION...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I THINK OUR BEST MEMORY IS...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>AN ADVENTURE I WANT TO SHARE WITH YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I TRUST YOU BECAUSE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I FELL IN LOVE WITH YOU WHEN...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>RECEIVE A HUG...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date One</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I REALLY APPRECIATE WHEN YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>You MAKE ME REALLY HAPPY WHEN...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I BELIEVE IN YOU BECAUSE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>SOMETHING SILLY l WANT TO DO WITH YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I WANT TO PAMPER YOU BY...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>A SMALL DOSE OF ROMANCE WOULD INCLUDE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>HOLD HANDS WITH EYES CLOSED...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Two</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>A GIFT I WOULD LIKE TO RECEIVE FROM YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Three</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>ONE THING I HAVE LEARNED FROM YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Three</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I WANT TO SHOW YOU SUPPORT BY...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Three</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>WHAT IS YOUR FAVOURITE ROMANTIC MOVIE? WHY?</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Three</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>MY ATTRACTION TO YOU DEEPENED WHEN...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Three</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I Think OUR RELATIONSHIP IS AT ITS BEST WHEN...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Three</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>WRITE YOUR PARTNER A THANKYOU NOTE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I WAS FIRST ATTRACTED TO YOU BECAUSE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>You BRING OUT THE BEST IN ME BY...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I&apos;D LIKE TO STUDY _ WITH YOU.</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>SOMETHING CRAZY I WANT TO DO WITH YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>ONE WAY TO TREAT OURSELVES TOGETHER...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I THINK OF US WHEN l HEAR THIS SONG...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Four</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>RECEIVE A HEAD MASSAGE.</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>MY EARLIEST MEMORY OF OUR FRIENDSHIP...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>SOMETHING EXCITING WE CAN DO TOGETHER...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>OUR IDEAL DAY TOGETHER...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>IF I COULD BUY YOU ANYTHING I WOULD BUY YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I FEEL CLOSE TO YOU WHEN...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>DESCRIBE A ROMANTIC EVENING</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>WRITE YOUR PARTNER A COMPLIMENT NOTE.</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Five</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>THE TALENT OF YOURS I REALLY LIKE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I ADMIRE THAT YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I WANT TO THANK YOU FOR...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>A SURPRISE I&apos;D LIKE FROM YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I LOVE YOU BECAUSE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>MY EARLIEST MEMORY OF OUR ROMANCE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>RECEIVE A SHOULDER MASSAGE</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Six</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>ONE OF YOUR STRENGTHS...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>WARM UP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>ONE PLEASURE I WOULD LIKE TO GIVE YOU...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>OUR LOVE REMINDS ME OF THIS CANDY...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I FEEL SAFE WITH YOU BECAUSE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I WANT YOU TO PAMPER ME BY...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>I THINK YOU ARE SEXY BECAUSE...</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Card</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>LOOK INTO EACH OTHERS EYES.</string>
    <key>mode</key>
    <string>TRY THIS</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>Date Seven</string>
    <key>customText</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
```

Comment: `NSArray(contentsOfFile: "path/to/plist")` is your friend. Modify the array and write it back out.

Comment: First of all, you load your cards from this plist with dictionary?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes

Comment: then you need a method convert your cards to NSDictionary and then save to plists?

Comment: Hello, I have been thinking and I have a question your plist is inside your NSBoundle or in your NSDocuments directory?

Comment: @StarShowsStudios I am reviewing my old answers, this answer help you in some way? if not i will deleted, please let me know thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that you need is convert your `Card` class to `Dictionary` then you need to save this dictionary to plist, in order to do that you must put this method in your card class. Note that if you use some Class as attribute of this Card class you must to convert this class also to dictionary

```
func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary
    {
        let returnDict = NSMutableDictionary();
        returnDic.setObject(title, forKey: "title");
        returnDic.setObject(name, forKey: "name");
        //**PUT ALL YOUR ATTRIBUTES IN THE DICTIONARY//

        return returnDict;
    }
```

and then you need to cicle over your cards and put your dictionaries on an Array an then you have to pass this array to this method

```
static func saveArray(array:NSArray,filename:String) ->Bool
{
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true);
    let docsDirectory = paths[0];
    let path = docsDirectory + "/" + filename;
    return array.writeToFile(path, atomically: true);
}
```

I Hope this helps you